# Query em índice de subdocumento do MongoDB com PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb

preciso de uma força. Possuo um banco MongoDB com um documento contendo outros documentos, e preciso criar uma query no PHP a partir de uma chave desse subdocumento. Segue a estrutura.

```
{
 "_id": "pastadigital",
 "v": {
  "docs": {
   "RG": {
    "tit": "RG",
    "obr": "S",
    "p": "F",
    "x": "1"
   },
   "CPF": {
    "tit": "CPF",
    "obr": "S",
    "p": "F",
    "x": "1"
   },
   "CNPJ": {
    "tit": "CNPJ",
    "obr": "S",
    "p": "J",
    "x": "2"
   },
  }
 }
}
```

Há diversos documentos, até então eu simplesmente buscava tudo e iria filtrando os resultados na aplicação. Minha query hoje está simplesmente assim:

```
<?php
$mon = new mongo();
$filter = ["_id" => ['$in' => ["pastadigital"]]];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, []);
$pastadig = $mon->Conn->executeQuery('sistema.confs', $query)->toArray();
```

Mas agora surgiu a necessidade de buscar de acordo por aquela chave "x". Então eu preciso fazer uma busca, algo como `['v.docs.*.x' => '1']`. Sendo o * como qualquer índice que contenha o x = 1

Tentei com regex ou procurar alguma Wildcard pra índices mas não achei nada. Alguma luz?

Comment: Não funcionou é isso?

Comment: Não, na verdade não consegui montar essa query e buscar somente os resultados a partir do índice 'x'

Comment: basicamente isso funciona: `{$or: [{'v.docs.RG.x': '1'}, {'v.docs.CPF.x': '1'}, {'v.docs.CNPJ.x': '1'}]}`

Comment: Sim nesse cenário funciona, mas não vou poder informar manualmente esses documentos (RG, CPF) pois eles são preenchidos dinamicamente. Por isso eu precisava de um coringa nesse campo e aplicar o filtro diretamente no x.

Comment: Eu to procurando já teste com `*` e não deu certo.

Comment: Como assim preenchido manualmente: esses documentos são diferentes? não tem um padrão no documento?

Comment: O * foi como um exemplo, acredito que não sirva de fato como um coringa. Digo que essa é uma lista de documentos que é sempre alterada. Nem sempre vai ter o CPF, outro dia pode ter um documento a mais. Assim não consigo informar que é pra procurar em RG, em CPF, etc. Eu preciso substituir esse nome de documento por um coringa. Ou alguma espécie de função, que a cada documento, verificar se o 'x' é = 1 por exemplo. Mas com o Mongo não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Seguinte não tem um padrão também é muito prejudicial, mas, eu estou tentando achar a forma de fazer isso

Comment: a consulta seria `{ 'v.docs':{'$in':{'x':{'$gte':1}}}}` se  o v.docs fosse uma array, como não, precisa ser algo bem maior longo como @novic mencionou, sugiro que transforme-o em uma array, pós o nome das propriedades é igual a propriedade 'tit' dentro delas...

Comment: explicando: "$in" = iterar array a procurar de qualquer elemento que satisfaça a query:, query= x for GTE (greater than or equal; maior ou igual) a 1